# Accessing DOM information on the web

Tags: javascript, dom

I am new to document object model. Is there any java-doc like thing for DOM. I am having tough time figuring out the following javascript code.

```
myElements = document.getElementById('idName').elements // whose attribute is elements part of ? Element Object or Node?
for (var eachElement in myElements) {
    if (myElement[eachElement].type == 'checkbox' ) {
        // why do I have to do this? Specifically, why can't type be accessed as eachElement.type == 'checkbox'
     }
 }
```

I think the bigger problem is I am having tough time in accessing documentation. Any clues on both would be appreciated.

Comment: Mozilla's DOM Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Gecko_DOM_Reference

Comment: I do not see elements attribute in Element Object?

Comment: idName is a form. So, you need HTMLFormElement: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLFormElement

Comment: that makes total sense. thanks. but then what's the relation between Node and Element. 

Rather why should I have to access myElement[eachElement].type =?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already mentioned, the [MDC documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Gecko_DOM_Reference) is quite comprehensive.

> // why do I have to do this? Specifically, why can't type be accessed as eachElement.type == 'checkbox'

`.elements` returns a [`HTMLCollection` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/HTMLCollection). This is an *array-like* data structure which can be traversed via a `for` or [`for...in` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop.

`for...in` loops over properties of objects. The *property name* (the index, so to speak, not its value) is stored in the loop variable, hence, to access the corresponding value, you have to write `obj[prop]`.

That is also the reason why you should not use `for...in` here. You don't know whether it also loops over other properties of the collection that are not elements.

Use a normal `for` loop:

```
var myElements = ...;
for(var i = myElements.length; i--; ) {
    var element = myElements[i];
    //...
}
```

I suggest to also read the [JavaScript guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide) to learn more about loops, arrays and objects.

Answer (score 2):

`.elements` property exists only for `form` elements https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLFormElement

So in your case, the `idName` has to point to a form element with `id="idName"`, otherwise it would cause an error.

The `elements` property will return a collection of form controls. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/form.elements

Comment: then once have a node why can't I access type without deferencing from the NodeList again.

Rather why should I have to access myElement[eachElement].type =?

Comment: @kuriouscoder: That's how loops work. Have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

Comment: @kuriouscoder The first argument in `for..in` loop is not a value but the index.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what it says:

```
myElements = document.getElementById('idName').elements 
//Find the form with the id="idName"
//and gather all the form elements in an object/array

//because there could be more than one element in the form, 
//you will need to loop through the object

//loop now and for each element that is a checkbox
//do the following, where it says DO SOMETHING

for (var eachElement in myElements) {
    if (myElement[eachElement].type == 'checkbox' ) {

    //DO SOMETHING

     }
 }
```